# Help with centering Table header in pgfplotstable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pgfplotstable

I would like some guidance to get my table's header to look like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=4in,bottom=4in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{good.csv}
Iter   dr21   dr31   dr22   dr32
     1 0.4900713 0.5051498 0.4907129 0.5064977
     2 0.4900256 0.5046520 0.4902557 0.5015202
     3 0.4894412 0.5044207 0.4844121 0.4992068
     4 0.4893335 0.5046210 0.4833348 0.5012102
     5 0.4898289 0.5045439 0.4882890 0.5004394
     6 0.4896377 0.5047679 0.4863770 0.5026787
     7 0.4897240 0.5049742 0.4872398 0.5047422
     8 0.4897114 0.5049562 0.4871140 0.5045621
     9 0.4897422 0.5049461 0.4874222 0.5044614
    10 0.4897475 0.5048733 0.4874748 0.5037328
\end{filecontents}%

\begin{document}

%%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
          every head row/.style={output empty row},
        }
    }
}{
    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
            typeset cell/.append code={%
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}

{\scriptsize
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,empty header,
columns={Iter,dr21,dr31,dr22,dr32},      % display specified columns
begin table=\bgroup\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable}\egroup,
columns/Iter/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=0,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/dr21/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/dr31/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/dr22/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/dr32/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
every head row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{Tabulated Data with the Various Parameters for Step 4.}%
    \label{tab:DataTable}\\\toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Iter$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{m{1.5cm}}{\centering $N(0,0.001^{2})$ $(\delta r_{2})$}  &
    \multicolumn{2}{m{1.5cm}}{\centering $N(0,0.001^{2})$ $(\delta r_{3})$}  &
    \multicolumn{2}{m{1.5cm}}{\centering $N(0,0.01^{2})$ $(\delta r_{2})$}  &
    \multicolumn{2}{m{1.5cm}}{\centering $N(0,0.01^{2})$ $(\delta r_{3})$}  \\ \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{10}{c}%
    {{\normalsize\emph{\bfseries{Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}}}} \\
    \toprule
    %
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Iter$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{m{1.5cm}}{\centering $N(0,0.001^{2})$ $(\delta r_{2})$}  &
    \multicolumn{2}{m{1.5cm}}{\centering $N(0,0.001^{2})$ $(\delta r_{3})$}  &
    \multicolumn{2}{m{1.5cm}}{\centering $N(0,0.01^{2})$ $(\delta r_{2})$}  &
    \multicolumn{2}{m{1.5cm}}{\centering $N(0,0.01^{2})$ $(\delta r_{3})$} \\ \toprule
    \endhead
    %
    \midrule \multicolumn{10}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    %
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{10}{r}{{End of Table}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    }},
]{good.csv} \label{tabnonoise} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=4in,bottom=4in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{good.csv}
Iter   dr21   dr31   dr22   dr32
     1 0.4900713 0.5051498 0.4907129 0.5064977
     2 0.4900256 0.5046520 0.4902557 0.5015202
     3 0.4894412 0.5044207 0.4844121 0.4992068
     4 0.4893335 0.5046210 0.4833348 0.5012102
     5 0.4898289 0.5045439 0.4882890 0.5004394
     6 0.4896377 0.5047679 0.4863770 0.5026787
     7 0.4897240 0.5049742 0.4872398 0.5047422
     8 0.4897114 0.5049562 0.4871140 0.5045621
     9 0.4897422 0.5049461 0.4874222 0.5044614
    10 0.4897475 0.5048733 0.4874748 0.5037328
\end{filecontents}%

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

%%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
          every head row/.style={output empty row},
        }
    }
}{
    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
            typeset cell/.append code={%
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}

{\scriptsize
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,empty header,
columns={Iter,dr21,dr31,dr22,dr32},      % display specified columns
begin table=\bgroup\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable}\egroup,
columns/Iter/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=0,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/dr21/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=7,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/dr31/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=7,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/dr22/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=7,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/dr32/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=7,fixed,fixed zerofill},
every head row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{Tabulated Data with the Various Parameters for Step 4.}%
    \label{tab:DataTable}\\\toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{$Iter$}} &
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{$N(0,0.001^{2})$} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$N(0,0.001^{2})$}\\\cmidrule(lr){3-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-10}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(\delta r_{2})$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(\delta r_{3})$} &
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(\delta r_{2})$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(\delta r_{3})$}      \\ \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{10}{c}%
    {{\normalsize\emph{\bfseries{Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}}}} \\
    \toprule
    %
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{$Iter$}} &
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{$N(0,0.001^{2})$} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$N(0,0.001^{2})$}\\\cmidrule(lr){3-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-10}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(\delta r_{2})$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(\delta r_{3})$} &
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(\delta r_{2})$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(\delta r_{3})$}      \\ \toprule
    \endhead
    %
    \midrule \multicolumn{10}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    %
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{10}{r}{{End of Table}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    }},
]{good.csv} \label{tabnonoise}

\end{document}
```

[image]