# Problem with centering header in pgfplots table

Tags: vertical-alignment, pgfplotstable

I followed some of the posts that deals with centering of the headers in the pgfplots table, line that found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277224/help-with-centering-table-header-in-pgfplotstable), however, I still cannot seem to be able to center the headers over the number in the columns.  Can you assist me in getting the headers center aligned with the numbers? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{dataa.dat}
k      z   xbar   Pkp1   Kkp1
1 12.0000 10.0000 0.2222 0.1111
2 17.7735 15.7735 1.3846 0.6923
3 21.1068 19.1068 0.5306 0.2653
4 23.0313 21.0313 0.9703 0.4851
5 24.1424 22.1424 0.6801 0.3401
6 24.7839 22.7839 0.8474 0.4237
7 25.1543 23.1543 0.7422 0.3711
8 25.3682 23.3682 0.8050 0.4025
\end{filecontents}%

\begin{document}

%%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
          every head row/.style={output empty row},
        }
    }
}{
    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
            typeset cell/.append code={%
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}

\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\bgroup\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable}\egroup,
}

\pgfplotstableset{
    % #1 = row index
    % #2 = row style keys
    row style/.style 2 args={
        every row #1 column 0/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 1/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 2/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 3/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 4/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 5/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 6/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 7/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 8/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 9/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 10/.style={#2},
    }
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,
empty header,
columns/k/.style={column type={c},fixed zerofill,precision=0,dec sep align},
columns/z/.style={column type={c},fixed zerofill,precision=4,dec sep align},
columns/xbar/.style={column type={c},fixed zerofill,precision=4,dec sep align},
columns/Pkp1/.style={column type={c},fixed zerofill,precision=4,dec sep align},
columns/Kkp1/.style={column type={c},fixed zerofill,precision=4,dec sep align},
every first row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{Tabulated Data for Problem 19-6(a)}%
    \label{tab:DataTable}\\\toprule
    &\multicolumn{1}{c} {$k$} &&  
    \multicolumn{1}{c} {$z$} &&
    \multicolumn{1}{c} {$\hat{x}_{k+1}$} &&  
    \multicolumn{1}{c} {$P_{k+1}$} &&
    \multicolumn{1}{c} {$K_{k+1}$} \\ \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{10}{r}%
    {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}} \\
    \toprule
    %
    &\multicolumn{1}{c} {$k$} &&
    \multicolumn{1}{c} {$z$} &&
    \multicolumn{1}{c} {$\hat{x}_{k+1}$} &&
    \multicolumn{1}{c} {$P_{k+1}$} &&
    \multicolumn{1}{c} {$K_{k+1}$} \\ \toprule
    \endhead
    %
    \midrule \multicolumn{10}{c}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    %
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{10}{r}{{End of Table}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    }},%
    %
]{dataa.dat}

\end{document}
```

Although I used the `\multicolumn{1}{c}` code, the headers are still not lining up correctly with the data.

Comment: Hello, is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{dataa.dat}
k      z   xbar   Pkp1   Kkp1
1 12.0000 10.0000 0.2222 0.1111
2 17.7735 15.7735 1.3846 0.6923
3 21.1068 19.1068 0.5306 0.2653
4 23.0313 21.0313 0.9703 0.4851
5 24.1424 22.1424 0.6801 0.3401
6 24.7839 22.7839 0.8474 0.4237
7 25.1543 23.1543 0.7422 0.3711
8 25.3682 23.3682 0.8050 0.4025
\end{filecontents}%

\begin{document}

%%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
          every head row/.style={output empty row},
        }
    }
}{
    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
            typeset cell/.append code={%
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}

\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\bgroup\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable}\egroup,
}

\pgfplotstableset{
    % #1 = row index
    % #2 = row style keys
    row style/.style 2 args={
        every row #1 column 0/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 1/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 2/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 3/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 4/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 5/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 6/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 7/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 8/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 9/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 10/.style={#2},
    }
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,
empty header,
columns/k/.style={column type={c},fixed zerofill,precision=0,dec sep align},
columns/z/.style={column type={c},fixed zerofill,precision=4,dec sep align},
columns/xbar/.style={column type={c},fixed zerofill,precision=4,dec sep align},
columns/Pkp1/.style={column type={c},fixed zerofill,precision=4,dec sep align},
columns/Kkp1/.style={column type={c},fixed zerofill,precision=4,dec sep align},
every first row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{Tabulated Data for Problem 19-6(a)}%
    \label{tab:DataTable}\\\toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c} {$k$}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c} {$z$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c} {$\hat{x}_{k+1}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c} {$P_{k+1}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c} {$K_{k+1}$} \\ \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{10}{r}%
    {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}} \\
    \toprule
    %
    \multicolumn{2}{c} {$k$}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c} {$z$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c} {$\hat{x}_{k+1}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c} {$P_{k+1}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c} {$K_{k+1}$} \\ \toprule
    \endhead
    %
    \midrule \multicolumn{10}{c}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    %
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{10}{r}{{End of Table}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    }},%
    %
]{dataa.dat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Commenting from your post, I just needed to increase the `\tabcolsep` to 10pt and change the `\multicolumn{1}{c}` to `\multicolumn{2}{c}`?