# pgfplot table cannot compile 2

Tags: pgfplotstable

For some reason, I cannot compile my pgfplot table.  Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=4in,bottom=4in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
          every head row/.style={output empty row},
        }
    }
}{
    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
            typeset cell/.append code={%
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}
\begin{filecontents}{data133.dat}
  iter theta1    r2v    r3v      x      y
     1 49.68590 1.08195 0.09195 1.40000 1.65000
     2 49.85442 1.08549 0.09549 1.39970 1.65951
     3 50.03335 1.08882 0.09882 1.39879 1.66899
     4 50.22198 1.09195 0.10195 1.39729 1.67839
     5 50.41959 1.09485 0.10485 1.39519 1.68767
     6 50.62543 1.09752 0.10752 1.39251 1.69681
     7 50.83875 1.09996 0.10996 1.38926 1.70575
     8 51.05880 1.10214 0.11214 1.38544 1.71447
     9 51.28480 1.10407 0.11407 1.38108 1.72293
\end{filecontents}%

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,empty header,
columns={iter,theta1,r2v,r3v,x,y},      % display specified columns
begin table=\bgroup\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable}\egroup,
columns/Iter/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=0,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/theta1/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/r2v/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/r3v/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/x/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/y/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
every head row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{Tabulated Data with the Various Parameters.}%
    \label{tabnonoise}\\\toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Iter$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\theta_{1}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{2v}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{3v}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$y$}\\ \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{12}{r}%
    {{\normalsize\emph{\bfseries\textcolor{mybluei}{Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}}}} \\
    \toprule
    %
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Iter$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\theta_{1}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{2v}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{3v}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$y$}\\ \toprule
    \endhead
    %
    \midrule \multicolumn{12}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    %
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{12}{r}{{End of Table}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    }},%
    %outfile=pgfplotstable.example1.out.tex
    %
]{data133.dat} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had not defined the colour blue that you use, and had specified 12 columns rather than 11 in the headings (the first integer column isn't doubled)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=4in,bottom=4in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\definecolor{mybluei}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\usepackage{filecontents}

%%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
          every head row/.style={output empty row},
        }
    }
}{
    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
            typeset cell/.append code={%
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}
\begin{filecontents}{data133.dat}
  iter theta1    r2v    r3v      x      y
     1 49.68590 1.08195 0.09195 1.40000 1.65000
     2 49.85442 1.08549 0.09549 1.39970 1.65951
     3 50.03335 1.08882 0.09882 1.39879 1.66899
     4 50.22198 1.09195 0.10195 1.39729 1.67839
     5 50.41959 1.09485 0.10485 1.39519 1.68767
     6 50.62543 1.09752 0.10752 1.39251 1.69681
     7 50.83875 1.09996 0.10996 1.38926 1.70575
     8 51.05880 1.10214 0.11214 1.38544 1.71447
     9 51.28480 1.10407 0.11407 1.38108 1.72293
\end{filecontents}%

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,empty header,
columns={iter,theta1,r2v,r3v,x,y},      % display specified columns
begin table=\bgroup\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable}\egroup,
columns/Iter/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=0,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/theta1/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/r2v/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/r3v/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/x/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
columns/y/.style={column type={c},dec sep align,precision=4,fixed,fixed zerofill},
every head row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{Tabulated Data with the Various Parameters.}%
    \label{tabnonoise}\\\toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$Iter$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\theta_{1}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{2v}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{3v}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$y$}\\ \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{11}{r}%
    {{\normalsize\emph{\bfseries\textcolor{mybluei}{Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}}}} \\
    \toprule
    %
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$Iter$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\theta_{2}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{2v}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r_{3v}$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$x$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$y$}\\ \toprule
    \endhead
    %
    \midrule \multicolumn{11}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    %
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{11}{r}{{End of Table}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    }},%
    %outfile=pgfplotstable.example1.out.tex
    %
]{data133.dat} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.  From previous post dealing with this issue, they recommended double the columns as the headers will become skewed as shown in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279413/problem-with-centering-header-in-pgfplots-table.  Although your suggestion compiles now, my headers are skewed now.

Comment: @Joe updated (package syntax seems excessively weird here:-)